# get referer after header("Location: http://B.com/");

Tags: php, http, redirect, http-redirect

A site **A** contains redirect at site **B**.

```
header("Location: http://B.com/");
```

I just need to know whether user came from **A** or not. 
On site **B** it is not possible to get referer with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

Thank you in advance for any other working solutions.

Comment: how about changing the redirect to sth like "...B.com/?comingfromA=1"?

Comment: Of course:) I wouldn't asked if I haven't tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GET variable to get this data.

```
header("Location: http://B.com/?refferer=A");
```

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about this. I'll take it if there is nothing more elegant.

Comment: Finally i used this method with sesstions and redirection from http://B.com/?refferer=A to http://B.com. Don't like get variables when unnesessary